# Different X Labels for Different Variables

Tags: python, seaborn

I have two data frames `t1` and `t2`. I want a seaborn plot where it plots side by side for every variable using the for loop. I was able to achieve this but I fail when I try to set the customized x labels. How do I incorporate `set_xlabel` in to the for loop?

```
data1 = {
    'var1': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'var2': [20, 21, 19, 18],
    'var3': [5, 6, 7, 8]
    }

data2 = {
    'var1': [5. 2. 3. 5],
    'var2': [21, 18, 3, 11]
    'var3': [1, 9, 3, 6]
    }

  
t1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
t2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

xlabel_list = ["new_var1", "new_var2", "new_var3"]

def fun1(df1, df2, numvar, new_label):
    plt.tight_layout()

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
    sns.kdeplot(data = df1[numvar], linewidth = 3, ax=ax[0])
    sns.kdeplot(data = df2[numvar], linewidth = 3, ax=ax[1])

    ax[0].set_xlabel(new_label, weight='bold', size = 10)
    ax[1].set_xlabel(new_label, weight='bold', size = 10)    

for col in t1.columns: # how to incorporate the new_label parameter in the for loop along with col?
    fun1(df1 = t1, df2 = t2, numvar = col, new_label??)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip`:

```
for col, new_label in zip(t1.columns, xlabels_list):
```